# Adobe Illustrator: Lines with stroke < 2.0pt doesn't change color

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I created lines using the line segment tool in Adobe Illustrator (latest Adobe Cloud version) and I can't change the color of the stroke (through the Appearance panel) if the stroke weight is less than 2.0pt. 
[image]
If the stroke is 2pt or more, then the color around the line changes but not the line itself. 
[image]

The whole behavior is odd for me as I've never faced in Illustrator before.

Edit: added screen below with the line selected. [image]

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE.  Unfortunately I can't replicate your problem. There must be some hidden effect/stroke somewhere.  Perhaps show your layers panel with layers expanded so someone might be able to work out what's wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you can not see the line color applied to a thin path is because you have an appearance attribute applied to the whole layer and this affects all the elements.

[image]

To remove the layer attributes, click on the circle to the right of the layer name (target icon) and from the Appearance panel click on the forbidden icon (Clear appearance icon)

> The **Target icon**, the little round icon displayed at the far right of each individual layer in the Layers panel, is used to select every item on the layer. Click the circular **Target icon**, then apply a stroke, change a color, or apply a style to all the objects on the layer.

Answer (score 3):

In both screenshots you have deselected the line, so we don't see the appearance of the specific line.

It sounds like you have by accident added two strokes to the line. A black 2 pt stroke and a green stroke which becomes visible when it's larger than the black stroke:

[image]

Comment: I updated the post to include an image with the line selected. In it, you can see that there is only one stroke. I created the line using the line segment tool, btw, without any other extra steps.