# Why drawn path has no fill but is not transparent in Adobe Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, path, transparency

The drawn path has no fill, but it filled by a black color.

[image]

How to remove this black and make inner region of a path transparent?

Comment: Check the target icon, maybe there's a fill applied to the layer, see [this answer](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/122573/120647)

Comment: @Danielillo Yes, this help.